# asp.net mvc-4 and grunt-uglify

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

How to manage .min files generated by grunt-uglify and "debug" version?

If I set

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

or at web.config

```
<compilation debug="false" />
```

apparently the bundle concat all files by itself and don't use the min files generated by grunt.

All debug version has their own minify version at the same folder ex:

Folder A

- testA.js
- testA.min.js
- ...

Folder B

- testB.js
- testB.min.js
- ...

PS: I'm not referencing minified files in bundleConfig.cs.

What is the best solution to handle it? I need to use ONLY minified files generated by GRUNT at the release moment, and still using debug version when in development.

Answer (score 0):

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

This code works only if you're using BundleConfig.cs

I think that the best way for you is to create a custom UrlHelper that can build JS scripts url according to if you're in debug mode or not (this is pseudo-code) :

```
public static class UrlHelper
{
    public static string JsScript(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string baseFileName) {
        return HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
            ? urlHelper.Content(baseFileName + '.js')
            : urlHelper.Content(baseFileName + '.min.js');
    }
}
```

And for example, if you want to use it in your Razor view :

```
<script src="@Url.JsScript("~/js/folderA/testA")"></script>
```